# How to show value in php prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query and I want to print the "total" 
I want to print the total like I print "num_rows"
How can I do that ?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM( total) AS total FROM money");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            print $stmt->total;
```

my table structure are like this

```
id user monthly_pay total
1  Adam  1500       1500
2  Erik 1500       1500 
3  Mark  1500      1500
4 Gusta 1500       1500
5  Mike 1500       1500
```

I want to view the total "75000"

Comment: you used aggregate function so each time it would return a single row each time means your will get fixed result 1.

Comment: Now on Phpmyadmin it return only 1 result. because this is request for total

Comment: you are using sum() function which return a row and in result set you are fetching num_row so i would be 1 only

Comment: Do you mean that you want fetch one result? If so, I gave you answer

Comment: so what is the code that I should use in this case ?

Comment: use this $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  total AS total FROM money");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            print $stmt->num_rows;

Comment: I dont want number of rows I want the total of " total column "

Comment: I update my question so it is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strictly not needed to use prepared statements when not dealing with user-input, but there's no disadvantage using it either (should you expand the query to deal with variables/user-input, the ground-work is already done!). This means for a static query like this, you can just use normal `query()` functions.

However, using prepared statements like this, you need to bind the result and fetch it. Using `$stmt->num_rows` is going to trick you, as this will return the amount of rows returned by the query - which will only be 1. It will not return the result.

The snippet below has been modified to use `bind_result()` and `fetch()`. This will prepare the query, bind the results to `$sum` and fetch it.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM( total) AS total FROM money");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sum);
$stmt->fetch();
print "The sum is ".$sum;
```

References

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PDO::fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM( total) AS total FROM money");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            print_r($result);
```

Comment: thanks but this did not work , 
this should view the total like "150 000"

Comment: You'll get array like ['total'=> 150000]. So just type print_r($result['total'])

Comment: OP seems to be using `mysqli_*`, not PDO. `store_result();` and `$stmt->num_rows` are signs of that ;-)

Comment: @Qirel can you concretize, what do you mean? Cause in question  quy use PDO-approach and even without it there is analogs in mysqli_* for all functions

Comment: @Dmytrechko This seems to be `mysqli_`, not PDO - you can tell from `store_result()` and `$stmt->num_row` being used in the original question. These are `mysqli_` functions.